# Problem in hiding empty staves

Tags: piano, sibelius

Could anyone know a possible solution for sorting out this hiding empty stave problem?

(P.S) I'm using join multiple measure option, so does that make any problem for hiding?
[image: This is the problem]

Comment: Hi Sanjai S. Welcome to the site. It might help you get the best answer if you add to your post: 1) The version of Sibelius you're using, and 2) The steps you're currently taking to hide the staff.

Comment: @Sanjai S, you only want to hide the empty bar of the top stave right?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use the Hide Empty Staves function, because the top stave isn't completely empty.
If you want a 'cut-away' stave, the trick is to select the portion you want hidden and apply an Instrument Change to 'No instrument (hidden)'

There are a few Sibelius experts here.  Rather more in the official forum [www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3](https://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3) and the various Sibelius Facebook groups.